# button click event not firing after checking any radiobutton inside update panel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, radiobuttonlist, scriptmanager

I have an update panel in my aspx page having a radiobuttonlist and a button. When button is clicked without having selected any radiobutton from the list, the click event works fine but when i checked one of the radio button and then click on that button, there is no postback or button click event not firing. Below is the screenshot for the same:

[image]

Any suggestion or answers will be appreciated!!

Comment: Please show us the relevant markup.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the example below:

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class AjaxUpdatePanelExample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            RadioButtonList1.DataSource = new List<string> { "option 1", "option 2", "option 3" };
            RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblSelectedOption.Text = String.Format("Selected option - {0}",RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue);
    }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblSelectedOption" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```